# FileTransfering in iOS with XMPPFramework and XMPPSiFileTransfer

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmppframework

I got stuck with implementing File Transfer functionality using iOS XMPPFramework(XMPPSiFileTransfer). I have tried out different ways and finally I could sent a file transfer request and the recipient got the request. But even if they accepted nothing seems to tranferring. I tried to sent request to recipients in Spark/Windows machine and iMessage/Mac. In the XMPPSiFileTransfer class itself, I found the developer comment as follow 
"**It's the other way around when we are the initiator. We send the request by calling initiateFileTransferTo:withData and then wait for the iq result with the si namespace of http://jabber.org/protocol/si, send a disco#info response, open a SOCKS5 socket and then wait for the other side the connect to start the transfer.**"

When I send a request by calling the method initiateFileTransferTo, SiFileTranfer generates the following XML:

```
<iq type="set" id="8FF7E518-E518-4A98-B122-914A8345C638" to="rajesh.rajan@chat.speridian.com/Spark 2.6.3" from="sreelash.s@chat.speridian.com/b79f10d5"><si xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si" id="967DAA7A-F159-44D8-AD31-7C532AB459AD" mime-type="image/png" profile="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer"><file xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer" name="photoB29D9F41-EC41-41C8-AF6D-EA5E23FF906E.png" size="740"/><feature xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/feature-neg"><x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="form"><field var="stream-method" type="list-single"><option><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams</value></option></field></x></feature></si></iq>
```

Then I got the response on didRecieveIq as follows as mentioned in the developer comment.

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" id="8FF7E518-E518-4A98-B122-914A8345C638" to="sreelash.s@chat.speridian.com/b79f10d5" from="rajesh.rajan@chat.speridian.com/Spark 2.6.3" type="result"><si xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si"><feature xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/feature-neg"><x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit"><field var="stream-method"><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams</value></field></x></feature></si></iq>
```

When I got the result with si namespace in didRecieveIq, the disco#info is sent as follow

```
<iq type="get" id="12A7231B-D50A-469E-96B4-BD39278B77EF" to="rajesh.rajan@chat.speridian.com/Spark 2.6.3" from="sreelash.s@chat.speridian.com/b79f10d5"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/></iq>
```

and SOCKS5 socket is tried to open by calling the following method

```
- (id)initWithStream:(XMPPStream *)stream toJID:(XMPPJID *)aJid sid:(NSString *)sid
```

But I am getting "SOCKS5 Connection failed!" message. I am not able to identify what's the issue. Can anyone help me to sort out this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you need to make some modifications in the TURNSocket class XEP-0065.
 try this [xmpp](https://github.com/adamk77/XMPPFramework)

refer this[link](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/issues/215)

Comment: Thanks for the reply friend. Actually I was trying with the same link that you referred. In the old sdk, TurnSocket was not using any sid. I just copied the new TurnSocket framework and tried which was not working. Thats why I got confused. Have you made this working.

Comment: yes, i am getting the same error. I just copied the updated TurnSocket class to my project and tried. It was not working for me. Did you get this working ever?

Comment: yes, i am getting the same error. I just copied the updated TurnSocket class to my project and tried. It was not working for me. Did you get this working ever? Even if the socket connection is failing, couldn't find the reason for failure. It just fires the socket failure delegate in which TurnSocket object is getting as parameter. Do you have any idea to debug this case.

Comment: Thanks for quick response friend. In this post, IQ messages are not using. But I found one issue in my code at the point of [TURNSocket setProxyCandidates:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:xmppStream.hostName, nil]]; Here the xmppStream.hostName seems nil, so I hardcoded the domain name as part of testing, even that time it was not working. I couldn't find any working code for file transfering since last week. Do you have any other idea?